# The sum of all Fibonacci numbers up to a million

Tags: python

I have just started doing project Euler problem 2 and was wondering if someone could help me fix this script:

```
def fib():
    x,y = 0,1
    while True:
        yield x
        x,y = y, x+y

def even(seq):
    for number in seq:
        if not number % 2:
            yield number

def under_a_million(seq):
    for number in seq:
        if number > 4000000:
            break
        yield number   

print sum(even(under_a_million(fib())))
```

This code is supposed to find the sum of all the fibonacci numbers until a million. Right now I am running into some problem with line 7.

Comment: I indented your code so that it displays as code, but it looks like the indentation is messed up.  Have a look at it and straighten it out. -- Also, posting the exact traceback is often helpful for these things.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code into a file and ran it with python 2.7 and it worked.

Comment: sorry about not including the traceback. There was none. Just a red line by line 7.

Comment: If you like generating a lot you should try a functional programming language.

Comment: yeah, @mgilson corrected it

Comment: @seamonkey8: FYI, the problem statements is *four* million

Comment: A red line?  I don't know what editor you're using, but it might be warning you that you mixed spaces and tabs or something like that.  To check, run with `python -t`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello Seamonkey and welcome to SO. I am happy that you have put more effort into this question than your last :)

I am going to walk through the code with you step by step. For simple problems, I find that it is easier to *not* use functions, as they can be annoying when one has to deal with global variables

```
#This part of the code gets the entire fibonacci sequence
list_of_numbers = []
even_fibs = []
x,y = 0,1 #sets x to 0, y to 1
while y <= 4000000: #Gets numbers till 4 million
    list_of_numbers.append(y)
    x, y = y, x+y #updates the fib sequence
```

In this block of code, (you can change it to a function if you wish), we calculate the full fibonacci sequence, up to 4 million. We also create two lists, `list_of_numbers` and `even_fibs`. The first is used to store the full sequence, the second is used to help us to store the even numbers. On to the next block.

```
coord = 0
for number in range(len(list_of_numbers)):
    test_number = list_of_numbers [coord]

    if (test_number % 2) == 0:
        even_fibs.append(test_number)
    coord+=1
```

Here I tested if numbers within the list `list_of_numbers` were even. If they were, I added them to the `even_fibs` list. You can read up on lists [here](http://www.sthurlow.com/python/lesson06/).

```
print "Normal:  ", list_of_numbers #outputs full sequence
print "\nEven Numbers: ", even_fibs #outputs even numbers
print "\nSum of Even Numbers:  ", sum(even_fibs) #outputs the sum of even numbers
```

This simply outputs our findings.

---

Since you seem to be fond of functions, I added the code here. The explanation is the same as it is up top.

```
#This part of the code gets the entire fibonacci sequence
list_of_numbers = []
even_fibs = []

def fib(list_of_numbers):

    x,y = 0,1 #sets x to 0, y to 1
    while x+y <= 4000000: #Gets numbers till 4 million
        list_of_numbers.append(y)
        x, y = y, x+y #updates the fib sequence
    return list_of_numbers

def even(list_of_numbers, even_fibs):
    coord = 0
    for number in range(len(list_of_numbers)):
        test_number = list_of_numbers [coord]

        if (test_number % 2) == 0:
            even_fibs.append(test_number)
        coord+=1
    return even_fibs

fib(list_of_numbers) #call fib function

even(list_of_numbers, even_fibs) #Call the even function
#Output
print "Normal:  ", list_of_numbers
print "\nEven Numbers: ", even_fibs
print "\nSum of Even Numbers:  ", sum(even_fibs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code can run with no problem.
At least the version after my edition.

If you did get error in your code, it's probably because of **wrong indentation**?
I run this code with no problem.

Note, the question is "Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed **four million**, find the sum of the even-valued terms"

So

```
def fib():
    x,y = 0,1
    while True:
        yield x
        x,y = y, x+y

def even(seq):
    for number in seq:
        if not number % 2:
            yield number

def under_a_million(seq):
    for number in seq:
        if number > 4000000: # <------------
            break
        yield number   

print sum(even(under_a_million(fib())))
```

BTW, good to see generators being used. It's almost like lazy evaluation in Haskell :)

Answer (score 1):

Below is my simple function for the Euler 2 challenge. In Python 3.0 I hope that it will offer some insight.

```
def sum_even_fib(n):#n is the upper_limit value for item in fib list
    list_numbers=[]
    a,b=0,1#initializing
    while b<n:#exits if condition fail
        list_numbers.append(b)
        a,b=b,a+b
    even_fib =[i for i in list_numbers if i%2==0]
    result=sum(even_fib)
    return result
```